# AWS REST Api gateway: Create Integration Request header from context data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm not able to create new header in Request Integration using context data.

I've used an lambda authorizer to return context and mapped them in Template Mapping.

Response from lambda authorizer:

```
{ 
  <<allow policy here>>,
  "context": {
    "uid": "some user id"
  }
}
```

**Attempt 1:**

But, I was not able to use data from context to generate header for integration.

```
HTTP Headers
------------------------------------------
| Name      | Mapped from                |
------------------------------------------
| myheader  | context.authorizer.uid     |
------------------------------------------
```

The uid does not get mapped to myheader field, nor the header shows up.

**Attempt 2:**

I've also tried using in VTL to remap `$input.params().header.myheader = "$context.authorizer.uid"` using Template Mapping and tried to map that header

```
HTTP Headers
---------------------------------------------
| Name       |      Mapped From             |
---------------------------------------------
| myheader   |method.request.header.myheader|
---------------------------------------------
```

This also didn't worked for me. What is the possible solution to send `"some user id"` in integration request header?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to put `$context.authorizer.uid` in Attempt 1.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-override-request-response-parameters.html

PS: The above reference says

> Mapping template overrides cannot be used with proxy integration endpoints, which lack data mappings.

So do verify if your integration is "proxy integration"

**Edited:**

In the mapping template you have set a request header override by adding the following: #set($context.requestOverride.header.myheader = $context.authorizer.uid)

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-override-request-response-parameters.html#apigateway-override-request-response-parameters-override-request

Comment: When I try to use $context, it gives following error:
```Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression specified: $context.authorizer.uid]``` @user11666461

Comment: No It's not a proxy integration. Mapping templates and header mappings are available.